# How can I pass interpolation data inside an attribute on a directive that is inside a function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to pass data inside of an attribute that is associated with a directive. The directive is inside a function on an `ng-click`. The value for "something" is an empty string (I think - it's just blank) in the console. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, what recommendations do you have for trying to achieve this?

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="showPopUp('<my-directive something={{some_data}}></my-directive>')"
<div>some_data = {{some_data}}</div> // I can see that some_data has a value
```

Javascript:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        something: '@something'
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/my_view.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        console.log($parse(attr.something)(scope)); // undefined
        console.log(scope.something); // nothing is displayed
    }
};
});
```

Comment: What are you doing in showPopup? And you dont need to put `\'` just do `something={{some_data}} ` interpolation will place the string value as attribute. Are you loading `some_data` asyncronously? if so wait and use a watch till the data is available. Ex http://plnkr.co/edit/clM0SJ?p=preview

Comment: When I try ``something={{some_data}}`` I get ``undefined`` in the console on ``$parse(attr.something)(scope)`` and I get nothing (an empty string?) in the console on ``scope.something``. I know ``{{some_data}}`` has a value because I added it to a ``div`` in the page and saw that its value is set. Also, I'm not loading ``some_data`` asyncronously.

Comment: Did you see my demo link? Is it similar to what you are doing? Can you update with a demo showcasing your issue? So that we can try to help you. What are you doing in the showpopup? You don't need `$parse` in your case and even if you use it it wont help you on isolated scope.

Comment: The popup just displays a form where a user can make a post. Thanks for posting the code sample, but I tried the $watch technique you came up with and it didn't work.

Comment: You need to show us what you are really doing. With the code sample you have in the question it should work. But your issue lies somewhere else. _"popup just display as form"_ do you believe there is no issue there (since you are not showing us that part)?

Comment: When I inspect my page I see ``<my-directive something=my_value></my-directive>``. Isn't this a problem, since there are no quotes around "my_value"? Is this why I'm getting a blank result when I try to console.log ``scope.something`` from within the directive?